# Using custom table for jsTree without hardcoding

Tags: php, jstree

Am using jsTree + PHP, and I would like to load up two different trees from two different database tables, depending on what user type the logged in user is.

I tracked down the code to the "class.tree.php" file,

```
class json_tree extends _tree_struct {  
function __construct($table = 'tree', $fields = array(), $add_fields = array("title" => "title", "type" => "type")) {
parent::__construct($table, $fields);
    $this->fields = array_merge($this->fields, $add_fields);
    $this->add_fields = $add_fields;
}
```

Where the $table = 'tree' is hard-coded. I tried removing it (so just $table), and passing 'tree' through as

```
$jstree = new json_tree('tree');
```

but that didn't work. Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about two different instances on one page? Or you one jsTree on a page based on some condition?

Comment: One jsTree on a page based on some condition. So, if type = 1, I get one tree; else I get the other tree.

Comment: So what is not clear about that? Is that an existing project?

Comment: Am trying to pass in the table, but it keeps on only saying "Loading" rather than showing the tree, regardless of the condition. Even when I simply try to pass the variable in without any conditions, it only says "Loading."

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle sample? Is that jsTree question or php one? I am bit lost in the picture.

Comment: It's a PHP question - how do I pass in the variable to jsTree so it doesn't show "Loading". http://www.jstree.com/demo shows an example, last one on the page; however, they have the tree table hardcoded.

Comment: Can you give me original php and what you modified? Was the original code working? Can you also provide jsTree definition?

Comment: The original is in the post itself. The modded is:
`class json_tree extends _tree_struct {  
function __construct($table, $fields = array(), $add_fields = array("title" => "title", "type" => "type")) {
parent::__construct($table, $fields);
    $this->fields = array_merge($this->fields, $add_fields);
    $this->add_fields = $add_fields;
}
`
and passing the variable as
`$jstree = new json_tree('tree');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those curious, I had completely forgotten that server.php also includes a jstree (I had also initiated it in my left menu). For those interested, or who need a conditional based tree, what I did was:

- removed the $table = 'tree' in the __construct as above, which becomes 
  `function __construct($table, $fields = array(), $add_fields = array("title" => "title", "type" => "type"))`
- added a session to the config.php (session_start())
- I have a log in, which allows me to get the condition
- in server.php, I did the following
  `if($_SESSION['condition'] == 1) { $jstree = new json_tree("tree");}
  else { $jstree = new json_tree("tree_users");}`

I hope this helps someone!